# My brand new acoustic guitar's bridge has crack?

Tags: acoustic-guitar, beginner, bridge

Alright So today I received my Kadence Frontier Series which I had ordered online.
The guitar's sound is really cool and everything else was good until I found a thin crack at the bridge.
What should I do?
Should I return it ? or just get it repaired ?[image]

Comment: Just send it straight back… and by the looks of that it didn't happen in transit, but at manufacture. That would make me extremely wary of the brand & their QA process… I'd be more than inclined to pick a different brand.

Comment: Surely the question is rhetorical. New item, not fit for purpose, returned, money refunded, search on for a better quality instrument, provided by a faculty which does far better pre-delivery inspections. Having said that, I've just mended a 12 string bridge that was in far worse condition. But - the guitar is 40 yrs old (guarantee had expired..!).

Comment: Also tell the dealer you were sent a defective product and shouldn’t have to pay for return shipping.

Comment: alright guys I'll return it

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - depending on what jurisdiction you are in, that is a statutory right & not one you have to ask for.